# Expanding column based on another column's grouping (dplyr/tidyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2, tidyr

I'm trying to convert a table like this:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   user_id        pred
     <int>      <fctr>
1       27 electronics
2       27        home
3       38      health
4       60 electronics
5       60      beauty
6       92        home
7       92 electronics
8      106      health
9      117        home
10     117       women
```

to one that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  user_id      pred_1      pred_2
    <dbl>       <chr>       <chr>
1      27 electronics        home
2      38      health          NA
3      60 electronics      beauty
4      92        home electronics
5     106      health          NA
6     117        home       women
```

i.e. a row per `user_id` and an expansion of the `pred` column into `pred_1`, `pred_2`, etc. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Initial question was solved. Follow up:

Using the `tidyr::spread` method, is there a way to cap the `group_size` to `N` so that, when spreading, it takes at most `N` values from each group?

Comment: Or using the devel version of data.table `library(data.table) ; dcast(setDT(df), user_id ~ rowid(user_id))`

Comment: Thanks everyone, but I don't really see how this is a duplicate of the other question. If anything, this is a much more succinct way of exposing `tidyr::spread`'s functionality

Comment: The solution there is identical. And there are dozens of similar solutions all over SO while many of them posted by same user. You can check some of them [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3732271+1%3A.N+dcast) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3732271+row_number+spread)

Comment: ok. I have an updated question (as well as a separate issue with the answer commented below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a sequence column after grouping by 'user_id' and then `spread` from 'long' to 'wide'.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(user_id) %>%
     mutate(id = paste0("pred_", row_number()), 
             id = factor(id, levels = unique(id))) %>%
     spread(id, pred)
#    user_id      pred_1      pred_2
#     <int>       <chr>       <chr>
#1      27 electronics        home
#2      38      health        <NA>
#3      60 electronics      beauty
#4      92        home electronics
#5     106      health        <NA>
#6     117        home       women
```

---

Or we can use `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)#1.9.7+
dcast(setDT(df1), user_id~paste0("pred_", rowid(user_id)), value.var = "pred")
```

Comment: I'm running into (what I deem to be) an error where the `pred_` values aren't in order. for example: the order of my columns goes `pred_1`, `pred_10`, `pred_11`, ... and so on. `pred_2` is in column 48

Comment: @NickResnick  I updated the post for dplyr/tidyr.  Please check if it helps.

Comment: thanks! can you also answer the updated question? Specifically, can you choose the number of columns it creates to be a number less than `max_grouping`?

Comment: @NickResnick   Can you post that as a new question as this got dupe tagged and it seems like an interesting question.

Comment: I just did. Also, I'm getting another error here where the same `user_id` is appearing in multiple rows, with only a partial amount of their `preds` in each row?

Comment: @NickResnick  What do you meant by `partial amount of their preds`?  Can you update it in your new post with an example data and error got?